# Detect Window Move in Property Page (win32)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-xp

I implemented a wizard using property sheet. One one page I display tooltip if user enters something invalid. It is a tracking tooltip so I have to manually turn it on and off. Now I want to move the tooltip when the wizard page moves.

It seems that only the property sheet window receives WM_MOVE event from Windows. The page does not. Is there a way to get notified in the page window when the wizard moved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property page isn't moving in relation to its parent window, the property sheet - that's why it's not getting WM_MOVE messages. You can set up a WM_MOVE handler in the property sheet and have it forward another message to the property page with PostMessage or SendMessage. I'd suggest a message in the WM_APP range.